# Laravel application and PHPUnit using sqlite, after executing the test database tables are dropped

Tags: laravel-7

I'm creating a Laravel7 application.

Laravel application and PHPUnit are using sqlite as database.

For the development in my local I have configured as follows

```
// .env
DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
DB_DATABASE=/path/to/db.sqlite
```

```
// phpunit.xml
<server name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>
<server name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/>
```

Step 1: Register a new user and able to successfully login

Step 2: Execute the test and it executes successfully

Step 3: Again login to application but it shows `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: users (SQL: select * from "users" where "id" = 1 limit 1)`

After executing the tests the existing tables are removed from the sqlite database even though the test's database is in `memory`

Note: In all my test classes I have `use DatabaseMigrations;` to include the trait.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Same issue here - did you get anywhere?

Comment: No, somehow our `.env` configuration is used for the `tests` too. I tried all the ways I can, but no success. No one is facing this issue, so it might be our issue but I'm not able to find. In laracast.com also I didn't get any solution. Now, I'm as usual `mysql` db and and for test `sqlite-memory`. Raised  an issue in Laravel issues but they said to contact laracast kind of sites.

Comment: Resetting the caches fixed this for me

Comment: @designvoid `php artisan clear-compiled && php artisan config:clear && php artisan cache:clear && php artisan view:clear && php artisan route:clear && sudo composer dump-autoload && php artisan optimize` This is the command usually I give :-) but not worked!